# Pineal gland reference?

Tags: matthew

Matthew 6:22-James Version

22 The light of the body is the eye: if therefore thine eye be single, thy whole body shall be full of light.

**Is this referring to the Pineal gland?**

There are 3 things that are found in the pineal gland- Calcium, Fluoride and phosphorus...phosphorus in Greek means "light bearer"... you all might be surprised  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorus

basic pineal gland info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pineal_gland

Answer (score 5):

### The pineal gland is not the 'eye that enlightens'

Our first description of the brain’s pineal gland and speculation about its function appears in a treatise by the surgeon/philosopher [Galen of Pergamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galen) written in Rome between 165 and 175 CE.  Greek philosophers had long thought that ***[pneuma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneuma#Classical_antiquity)*** – a fine, volatile, airy or vaporous substance composed of air (motion) and fire (warmth) – coursed through the human body, bringing consciousness to the brain and animation to the organs and body parts.  Stoics had come to believe there was a single *pneuma* system regulated by the heart.  But according to Galen, others believed there were two separate systems:  the pineal gland regulated the flow of ***psychic pneuma*** for the brain, and the heart regulated the ***vital pneuma*** for the body.  Galen argued for the double system, though he thought the *vermis superior cerebella*, rather than the pineal gland, the more likely structure to regulate the brain’s *pneuma* system.`1`

The relevance of this history to our question is that in addition to sustaining consciousness and animation, the Greeks considered *pneuma* the ‘breath of life’, the spirit, the substance of the human soul.  This is also the meaning often carried by the Greek word [*pneuma* in the Bible](http://www.biblestudytools.com/lexicons/greek/kjv/pneuma.html) (though it's unclear if Bible writers understood it as biological).

[Mt.6:22](http://biblehub.com/interlinear/matthew/6-22.htm), however, offers no insight on these issues.  Within a discussion about the corrupting influence of the envy for earthly treasures, this verse names the **eye** as the ‘lamp’ (λύχνος, *lychnos*) by which the whole body may be filled with either light (φωτεινός, *phōteinos*) or, in the next verse, darkness.  While this is surely [metaphorical language](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/8022/6884) for a moral lesson, there is no mention of spirit (πνεῦμα, *pneuma*), soul (ψυχή, *psychē*), or breath (πνοή, *pnoē*) in this discussion.  **Mt.6:22 does not name the pineal gland or even suggest any type of literal, biological function.**

But we should note that **the previous verse does reference the ‘heart’** (καρδία, *kardia*).  [Bible dictionaries](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G2588&t=NASB) often define the heart as the all-encompassing seat of the soul, mind, will, emotions and character, just as the heart was seat of the soul – the regulator of *pneuma* – for the Stoics.

Helpfully Galen shows there were also other views during the early New Testament era.  During the 1st century CE the [Pneumatic school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumatic_school) of Roman medicine had reasserted old distinctions between the heart (which housed the mind) and the brain (which housed the soul).  Galen went a step further and theorized a [tripartite soul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galen#Localization_of_function): the rational soul in the brain, the spiritual soul in the heart, and the appetitive soul in the liver.  It’s uncertain what our gospel writer intended by ‘heart’ in Mt.6:21, but it would be interesting to explore whether and how his usage reflects traditional Greek, Gnostic, Galen or uniquely Hebrew or Christian concepts of these ideas.

What is clear is that **there are no references to the pineal gland in the Bible.**  And even though Galen’s treatise reseating the *psychic pneuma* in another brain structure was highly influential, theories connecting the soul to the pineal gland resurfaced in the Middle Ages, and even in Descartes.  Spiritual interest in it today largely stems from New Age appropriation of Madam Blavatsky’s 19th C. Theosophy which claimed the pineal gland is an atrophied vestige of the mystical [‘third eye’](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_eye), the “organ of spiritual vision” offering awakening, clairvoyance, and higher states of consciousness.  Like many other New Age theories, this one has no basis in the Bible.

---

`1`  Lokhorst, Gert-Jan, ["Descartes and the Pineal Gland"](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pineal-gland/), The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (Fall 2015 Edition), Edward N. Zalta (ed.).

Comment: UPDATE:  Adding a link to David Bentley Hart's 2018 discussion of the meaning of 'spirit', 'soul', etc in the NT, for further reference:  
http://churchlife.nd.edu/2018/07/26/the-spiritual-was-more-substantial-than-the-fleshly-for-the-ancients/#menuopen

Answer (score -1):

The way I understand it is...we SEE with the eye.  When the eye is 'intertwined' (with the Lord)...wrapped around Him,
then all the body we have receives that spiritual light.
Jesus is mostly referencing spiritual matters but using concrete examples.
It's like the tree of LIFE...we refuse to see from 'good and evil', but entirely combine our vision with the Lord.
(We sometimes hear Christians claiming to sin, regretting, then sinning again...if what we saw was in twined consciously with Yehosgua, we would not look at darkness at all).

Comment: @2FollowHim-We will constantly sin in this life on earth, repenting and recognizing sin is What Jesus wants us to know. How would you know when you are seeing with one eye?